# How LinkedIn knows my dentist?

Tags: linkedin

I called my dentist recently to schedule an appointment. Didn't have to do any web searches since I already had the number. Once there, I did not make any payments with my credit card, didn't even have to show my insurance card since they already had that information. Not sure if I called from my iPhone or landline but I don't have LinkedIn app installed on my iPhone so it's irrelevant.

Today, I logged into LinkedIn and my dentist is first on the list of suggestions to connect to. Now, if that is not creepy, I don't know what is.

How in the world would they suggest my dentist since there were no emails exchanged with my dentist, no web searches of my dentist, no credit card transactions at the dentist office or anything else traceable?

Do they get data from the NSA or something? It's so creepy I'm considering closing my LinkedIn account.

Comment: LinkedIn suggestions can indeed appear creepy, but much of it has to do with what _other people_ share about you and what connections they might have made. If your name appears in someone else's email list they uploaded to linkedIn and _they_ have some connection with your dentist then....?

Comment: So my dentists shares with LinkedIn or someone else his appointments?

Comment: I doubt that he shares his "appointments". But what if a couple of your connections have a connection with your "dentist" (not necessarily a direct connection, but might have unwittingly uploaded the dentists contact details in their address book), it might be reasonable to assume that you "might" also have a connection with the "dentist", particularly if you live in the same town? But really, there's no way for us to know exactly what information LinkedIn used to make the suggestion.

Comment: That's plausible but why did this happen immediately after my appointment? Just a coincidence?

Comment: Perhaps your dentist was curious about you and looked you up?! Creepy! I'd get a new dentist! (_That was a joke; I hope!_)